# Get access to the file descriptor of a socket

Tags: c, sockets

This is part of a .c file that in included into a tcp server-client message service that has one client per thread; I want to use select inside the server thread to handle new incoming connections or data being written in a buffer but the problem I have is that I need the socket file descriptor to do that of the clients and of the server.

In this part of the code the socket descriptor of the server is inside s->sd but I can seem to access it outside this function because it returns (socket).

What can I do? (large parts of code are omitted to make it readable)

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

typedef struct {
  int sd; //id of the socket??
  char *ip_addr;
  int port;   
  } MySocket;   

Socket tcp_passive_open(int port) 
{                                                                                      
  MySocket *s = (MySocket *)malloc( sizeof(MySocket) );
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  s->sd = socket(PROTOCOLFAMILY, TYPE, PROTOCOL);

  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  addr.sin_family = PROTOCOLFAMILY;
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  if ( bind(s->sd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 ) {
    die("tcp_open_server failed(): bind() failed"); 
  }

  s->port = port;
  s->ip_addr = NULL;  //INADDR_ANY ...  
  return (Socket)s;  
}
```

main:

```
Socket server = tcp_passive_open( PORT );
FD_SET(SOCKETDESCRIPTOR_SERVER??,&master_socketDescriptors);
```

Comment: s is a pointer. You attempt to return the struct. Return the pointer instead (you will need to change the function's return type) . And remove all the casts, except the (struct sockaddr *). Also what is Socket? should that be MySocket?

Comment: bedankt wildplasser :) the problem is though that i want to try it without changing tcp_passive_open but maybe that's not possible. And socket is a filetype: i think (it not the struct no). So you're solution is not much help I'm afraid.

Comment: Why do you want to return Socket, while you just had the type MySocket typedeffed, malloc()ed, and initialised. Makes no sense to me. (IANAB;-)

Comment: What is `Socket`? There is no definition for it in your code.

Comment: it's from the socket api (edit: i will add the include so it's clear)

Comment: @wildplasser: it doesn't make sense for me too but that's what's inside the tcp_comm file;which i was given for an assignment.I know that by changing it and returning the fd or even the struct i can acces it but i was wondering if there was a way by keeping the code inside the tcp_comm.c file unchaned. A file that is included through it's .h file btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MySocket::sd` is the descriptor you need to use with `select()`.  Both `socket()` and `accept()` return socket descriptors that can be used with `select()`.  Change `tcp_passive_open()` to return a `MySocket*` instead of a `Socket`, then your main server thread will have access to the server's socket descriptor to pass to `select()` for detecting incoming connections, eg:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

typedef struct {
    int sd;
    char *ip_addr;
    int port;
} MySocket;

MySocket* tcp_passive_open(int port) {
    MySocket *s = (MySocket *)malloc( sizeof(MySocket) );
    if ( s == NULL ) {
        die("tcp_open_server failed(): malloc() failed");
    }

    s->sd = socket(PROTOCOLFAMILY, TYPE, PROTOCOL);
    if ( s->sd == -1 ) {
        die("tcp_open_server failed(): socket() failed");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    addr.sin_family = PROTOCOLFAMILY;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if ( bind(s->sd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 ) {
        die("tcp_open_server failed(): bind() failed");
    }

    s->port = port;
    s->ip_addr = NULL;  //INADDR_ANY ...
    return s;
}
```

.

```
MySocket* server = tcp_passive_open( PORT );
FD_SET(server->sd, &master_socketDescriptors);
```

Afterwards, when `select()` reports a pending inbound connection connection on the server socket, call `accept()` to accept the connection and obtain its socket descriptor, then you can allocate a separate `MySocket` for it:

```
int sd = accept(server->sd, ...);
if ( sd != -1 ) {
    MySocket *client = (MySocket*) malloc(sizeof(MySocket));
    client->sd = sd;
    ...
}
```

Then you can create a new thread for that `MySocket`, and that thread can call `select()` to detect inbound data on that connection as needed.

Comment: thx; i wanted to preserve tcp_passive_open because i supposly don't have acces to it (only to the .h file). Remember the "Socket server = tcp_passive_open( PORT );" is in another c file which include the .h file of the file where tcp_passive_open is defined. However i forgot to mention that inside that .h file there is a declaration: "typedef void * Socket;" maybe this could be used to get the socket descriptor?

Comment: ok; i solved it apparently this socket can be reconverted to the MySocket struct using: 
 Socket server = tcp_passive_open( PORT );
 MySocket *s = (MySocket *)server;
 printf("socket descriptor: %d",s->sd);
I don't know however why it needed to be converted to the socket (or why all the functions return socket instead of MySocket) but that's something i'll ask the person who gave me those files.
Thank you very much

Comment: Typical encapsulation practice. Whoever wrote the code in the first place was trying to hide the details of `MySocket` from outside code. That is why `Socket` maps to a plain `void*` pointer. That way, the contents of `MySocket` can be changed without affecting outside code. In which case, that code should have exposed some kind of `tcp_accept()` and `tcp_select()` functions that take `Socket` as input and handle the socket descriptors internally for you. If the code does not have such functions, then that was probably either an oversight or just sloppy programming on the author's part.

Comment: no it does have these functions but I needed the socket descriptors for the select; is it better to add functions that also handle these socket descriptors inside that same file; because to me this makes it a lot more complex